# Product Image Gallery similar to Amazon - jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery, photo

I've looked through a lot of the various image galleries but haven't really seen one that works similar to the Amazon product preview. I know creating one is an option, but its a bit out of my league right now. Has anybody came across any galleries that they may have used in the past that are similar?

Thanks

Product page with image previews.

[http://www.amazon.com/Water-Loud-130-dB-Alarm/dp/B00CGJN84I/ref=pd_sim_hi_2?ie=UTF8&refRID=17DDJM7RCJRT3GHKC81J](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CGJN84I)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got these links, might be helpful to you:

http://www.queness.com/post/3141/10-image-galleries-jquery-script-with-thumbnail-filmstrip

http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/thumbnail

These contain multiple gallery with different look and feel. You can try any of them for your work. You might have to play around with the options in them.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question because I was looking for the same thing. Here is the simple gallery plugin that I ended up installing:

**simpleGal**

GitHub Page: https://github.com/steverydz/simpleGal

Demo Page: http://steverydz.com/simpleGal/demo/

Comment: By now, none of these links seem to be active!